# Image Comparison Slider Containers Won't Flex Wrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Here's a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/Bryandbronstein/pen/NLVQjB

So this is a strange issue and I'm at the end of my rope with this one.  I've been learning a bit more about CSS and Javascript, and decided to try out an image comparison slider I found on W3C's website.  It works perfectly as a single element, however I want to have a full gallery of these.  Yet no matter what I try, they don't seem to want to obey any of the flex rules I set for their parent container.  You'll notice in the codepen that one comparison container is hidden behind another.  Any ideas?

```js
function initComparisons() {
          var x, i;
          /*find all elements with an "overlay" class:*/
          x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            /*once for each "overlay" element:
            pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function:*/
            compareImages(x[i]);
          }
          function compareImages(img) {
            var slider, img, clicked = 0, w, h;
            /*get the width and height of the img element*/
            w = img.offsetWidth;
            h = img.offsetHeight;
            /*set the width of the img element to 50%:*/
            img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
            /*create slider:*/
            slider = document.createElement("DIV");
            slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
            /*insert slider*/
            img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
            /*position the slider in the middle:*/
            slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
            slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
            /*execute a function when the mouse button is pressed:*/
            slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
            /*and another function when the mouse button is released:*/
            window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
            /*or touched (for touch screens:*/
            slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
             /*and released (for touch screens:*/
            window.addEventListener("touchstop", slideFinish);
            function slideReady(e) {
              /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
              e.preventDefault();
              /*the slider is now clicked and ready to move:*/
              clicked = 1;
              slider.style.border = "0";
              /*execute a function when the slider is moved:*/
              window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
              window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
            }
            function slideFinish() {
              /*the slider is no longer clicked:*/
              clicked = 0;
              slider.style.border = "3px solid white";
            }
            function slideMove(e) {
              var pos;
              /*if the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function:*/
              if (clicked == 0) return false;
              /*get the cursor's x position:*/
              pos = getCursorPos(e)
              /*prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image:*/
              if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
              if (pos > w) pos = w;
              /*execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor:*/
              slide(pos);
            }
            function getCursorPos(e) {
              var a, x = 0;
              e = e || window.event;
              /*get the x positions of the image:*/
              a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
              /*calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image:*/
              x = e.pageX - a.left;
              /*consider any page scrolling:*/
              x = x - window.pageXOffset;
              return x;
            }
            function slide(x) {
              /*resize the image:*/
              img.style.width = x + "px";
              /*position the slider:*/
              slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
            }
          }
        }
```

```css
html, body { 
          background-color: #333333;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
         }

        * {box-sizing: border-box;}

        .gallery_text {
          color: white;
          font-family: Abel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 1.7rem;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 1.8em;
        }

        .row{
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .img-comp-container{
          position: relative;
          flex: 50%;
        }

        .img-comp-overlay{
          border-right: 2px solid rgba(51,51,51, .5) ;
        }

        .img-comp-img {
          position: absolute;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .img-comp-img img {
          vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .img-comp-slider {
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 9;
          cursor: ew-resize;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          transform: rotate(136deg);
          background-color: #333333;
          opacity: .8;
          border-radius: 10%;
          border: 3px solid white;
        }
```

```html
 <body onload="initComparisons();">

 <div class="row">

   <div class="img-comp-container" >
     <div class="img-comp-img">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162389/lost-places-old-decay-ruin-162389.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=black-and-white-dark-building-162389.jpg&fm=jpg" width="500" height="450">
     </div>
      <div class="seperator"></div>
     <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSslfAcWKXuMxBpzcJC5ZUyFqMOb2Jtd12x4kBUGG9mTe3KeMJz" width="500" height="450">
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="img-comp-container">
     <div class="img-comp-img">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162389/lost-places-old-decay-ruin-162389.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=black-and-white-dark-building-162389.jpg&fm=jpg" width="500" height="450">
     </div>
      <div class="seperator"></div>
     <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSslfAcWKXuMxBpzcJC5ZUyFqMOb2Jtd12x4kBUGG9mTe3KeMJz" width="500" height="450">
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="img-comp-container">
     <div class="img-comp-img">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162389/lost-places-old-decay-ruin-162389.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=black-and-white-dark-building-162389.jpg&fm=jpg" width="500" height="450">
     </div>
      <div class="seperator"></div>
     <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSslfAcWKXuMxBpzcJC5ZUyFqMOb2Jtd12x4kBUGG9mTe3KeMJz" width="500" height="450">
     </div>
   </div>
  
 </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images won't wrap because all children of `.img-comp-container` were absolutely positioned. This collapsed all the flex elements so that the flex wrap wouldn't work.

Either make one of more of the children of `.img-comp-container` relative or static, or set a width and height to `.img-comp-container`.

Here are the changes I made to the CSS:

```
.img-comp-container{
  position: relative;
  flex: 50%;
}

.img-comp-img {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-comp-overlay {
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

[See this codepen fork](https://codepen.io/larsmagnus/pen/yxdLmx) of your pen for a working solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!  So does this apply to all instances of flex?  Any children of a flex enabled parent cannot have absolutely positioned elements inside them?

Comment: You're welcome! Children of flex containers can have absolutely positioned elements inside of them, but not *only* absolutely positioned elements – that will collapse the width and height. Flex children need some discernible content to calculate a width and height from so that the flexbox model can, for example, figure out when the elements should wrap.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function initComparisons() {
          var x, i;
          /*find all elements with an "overlay" class:*/
          x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            /*once for each "overlay" element:
            pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function:*/
            compareImages(x[i]);
          }
          function compareImages(img) {
            var slider, img, clicked = 0, w, h;
            /*get the width and height of the img element*/
            w = img.offsetWidth;
            h = img.offsetHeight;
            /*set the width of the img element to 50%:*/
            img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
            /*create slider:*/
            slider = document.createElement("DIV");
            slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
            /*insert slider*/
            img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
            /*position the slider in the middle:*/
            slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
            slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
            /*execute a function when the mouse button is pressed:*/
            slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
            /*and another function when the mouse button is released:*/
            window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
            /*or touched (for touch screens:*/
            slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
             /*and released (for touch screens:*/
            window.addEventListener("touchstop", slideFinish);
            function slideReady(e) {
              /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
              e.preventDefault();
              /*the slider is now clicked and ready to move:*/
              clicked = 1;
              slider.style.border = "0";
              /*execute a function when the slider is moved:*/
              window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
              window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
            }
            function slideFinish() {
              /*the slider is no longer clicked:*/
              clicked = 0;
              slider.style.border = "3px solid white";
            }
            function slideMove(e) {
              var pos;
              /*if the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function:*/
              if (clicked == 0) return false;
              /*get the cursor's x position:*/
              pos = getCursorPos(e)
              /*prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image:*/
              if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
              if (pos > w) pos = w;
              /*execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor:*/
              slide(pos);
            }
            function getCursorPos(e) {
              var a, x = 0;
              e = e || window.event;
              /*get the x positions of the image:*/
              a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
              /*calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image:*/
              x = e.pageX - a.left;
              /*consider any page scrolling:*/
              x = x - window.pageXOffset;
              return x;
            }
            function slide(x) {
              /*resize the image:*/
              img.style.width = x + "px";
              /*position the slider:*/
              slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
            }
          }
        }
```

```css
html, body { 
          background-color: #333333;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
         }

        * {box-sizing: border-box;}

        .gallery_text {
          color: white;
          font-family: Abel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 1.7rem;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 1.8em;
        }

        .row{
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .img-comp-container{
          position: relative;
          flex: 50%;
        }

        .img-comp-overlay{
          border-right: 2px solid rgba(51,51,51, .5) ;
        }

        .img-comp-img {
          position: absolute;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .img-comp-img img {
          vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .img-comp-slider {
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 9;
          cursor: ew-resize;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          transform: rotate(136deg);
          background-color: #333333;
          opacity: .8;
          border-radius: 10%;
          border: 3px solid white;
        }
```

```html
 <body onload="initComparisons();">

    <div class="row">

            <div class="img-comp-container" >
              <div class="img-comp-img">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162389/lost-places-old-decay-ruin-162389.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=black-and-white-dark-building-162389.jpg&fm=jpg" width="500" height="450">
              </div>
                <div class="seperator"></div>
              <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSslfAcWKXuMxBpzcJC5ZUyFqMOb2Jtd12x4kBUGG9mTe3KeMJz" width="500" height="450">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="img-comp-container">
              <div class="img-comp-img">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162389/lost-places-old-decay-ruin-162389.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=black-and-white-dark-building-162389.jpg&fm=jpg" width="500" height="450">
              </div>
                <div class="seperator"></div>
              <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSslfAcWKXuMxBpzcJC5ZUyFqMOb2Jtd12x4kBUGG9mTe3KeMJz" width="500" height="450">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="img-comp-container">
              <div class="img-comp-img">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162389/lost-places-old-decay-ruin-162389.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=black-and-white-dark-building-162389.jpg&fm=jpg" width="500" height="450">
              </div>
                <div class="seperator"></div>
              <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSslfAcWKXuMxBpzcJC5ZUyFqMOb2Jtd12x4kBUGG9mTe3KeMJz" width="500" height="450">
              </div>
            </div>
        
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).